# How do I add a ftp client file upload option to a website (for an architect or printer)

Tags: php, ftp, upload

I am so new to all of this I barely know what to ask.

As a reference, I am trying to achieve what the following website offers to their clients:

http://www.tokerassociates.com/ (click the ftp button on the top right, and it links to a form asking for a password and username. After which I'd guess there would be some kind of upload button).

They want their printers or their draftsmen to be able to send them oversized files via their website.

Could someone break this down for me? Seems there is a lot at work here.

I know I can create new FTP accounts through a server, and will require lots of GB in which to store them.

I need to code for a form wherein the client could login with a password. I'd also need another form where the client could click to upload files. Not sure if these could be in html or if it should be php?

Then I need to link these uploads with a specific folder in the architect's server.

Does anyone know of any tutorials a beginner could learn from? Or even an easy-to-implement paid program. I'd take any suggestions... So confused.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is a really "dangerous" way to introduce yourself to server programming - it would of course be more expensive but I would recommend that you get a third party to be your "Upload Site". There are a number of professional offerings of this sort, from "dropbox" mass-market style to more "we make a page that looks like your site" solutions.

Sorry I'm not really answering your question, hope this helps anyway!

Comment: http://yousendit.com offers a service where you embed a yousendit form on your website (very easy to do), and the file gets uploaded to their servers and emailed to you as a link to download.  Worked very well for handling large job applications for an HR client.

Comment: I agree with you, Tao. It is a request from my boss, who knows I only have 3 months of coding experience... Good to hear that my concerns are well founded. And wuckachucka, that's just the kind of direction I was seeking. Thank you both so much for your advice - which I will now more confidently follow... (I don't yet have enough points to give you both thumbs up).